# Spray REST API Application Structure - Suggestions Needed

Tags: scala, spray

I have the following multi-module project structure built using sbt:

```
myProject-api
myProject-core
```

myProject-core is organized as below:

It contains certain actors which acts as a facade to my services. For example., I have a UserActor that sits in front of a UserService. A NotificationActor that sits in front of a NotificationService and so on.

I have another trait that exposes there actors to anybody that is interested:

```
trait MyProjectCoreActors {

  def myAppCfg = MyProjConfig.appCfg      

  def userActor = myAppCfg.userActor
  def notifyActor = myAppCfg.notifyActor
}
object MyProjectCoreActors {

  ... some initialization routing that initializes the MyProjConfig
}
```

My UserActor is thus defined as:

```
class UserActor(service: UserService) extends Actor {

  ...
  ...
}
```

My UserService is as follows:

```
class UserService(dbConfig: DbConfig) {

  ...
  ...
}
```

I have another class called MyProjectConfig which I initialize using the application.conf file. In this file I have the connection details to the database and so on. The MyProjectConfig is initialized as below:

```
trait MyProjectConfig {

  def actorSystem: ActorSystem

  // the actors
  def userActor: ActorRef
}
object MyProjectConfig {

  def apply(appConfig: Config, system: ActorSystem): MyProjectConfig = {

    new MyProjectConfig {
      private val dbConfig = loadDBConfig(appConfig)

      override val actorSystem = system

      // each actor gets its own DBConfigInstance instance
      override val userActor =
        actorSystem.actorOf(
          Props(new UserActor(UserService(dbConfig)))
        )
    }
  }
}
```

I have now the Spray routing as defined below:

```
trait MyProjectService extends HttpService with MyProjectCoreActors {

  def pingRoute = path("ping") {
    get {
      userActor ! "newUser"
      complete("pong!")
    }
  }

  def pongRoute = path("pong") {
    get { complete("pong!?") }
  }

  def route = pingRoute ~ pongRoute
}
```

What is now missing is a way to call the MyProjectConfig.apply(....) method and pass in the Actor System and the underlying application.conf!

This was originally a Play based application, where I had a Lifecycle plug in which had access to the underlying Application from where I got the config and the actor system. How could I now get the same here with Spray?

I have a Boot class that looks like this:

```
object MyBootHttpService extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("myproj-actor-system")

}
```

How could I pass this ActorSytem to MyProjectConfig.apply(....)? and from where could I get the application.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do such things (DI) in your `MyBootHttpService` class.

For example

```
object MyBootHttpService extends App {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("myproj-actor-system")
  private val config = ConfigFactory.load
  private val myAppConfig = MyProjectConfig(config, actorSystem)

  // Initialise classes that depend on config and actorsystem....
  private val service = new MyProjectService with HttpServiceActor {
     override implicit val actorRefFactory = actorSystem
  }
  // Bind our service
  IO(Http) ? Bind(listener = service, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = config.getInt("port"))

}
```

Typesafe config library object `ConfigFactory` is generally used to load config files. `ConfigFactory.load` with no args will try and load `application.conf` from the classpath.